# Minimizing data sent between client/server in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, socket.io

I am trying to code a multiplayer game demo in javascipt using no libraries. Everything is going pretty good, but in order to get better performance to move forward I am going to have to try minimize the data I sent over my websockets or I won't be able to do much. I have been thinking about the best way to do this. I am using Node.JS + Express + Socket.IO.

At first I was sending the keyboard state of all the keys from each client to the server and quickly narrowed this down to true/false values for only the keys I was using. But now I am thinking that I should really be doing something like assigning decimal literal values (0, 1, 3, 4) to each possible input *state* that are allowed (possible combinations of inputs) and simply sending that value to the server.

I have more experience in statically typed languages such as C++, Java, etc. so I know how I would do this in those languages. But basically want I want to know is if I have a small number of possible input states. What is the best way to send this data using javascript on both ends. It will be going into a JSON object. Is there anyway for me to send a single byte?

Comment: With bit masking you can store 8 booleans in 1 byte.

Comment: `so I know how I would do this in those languages` how would you do this in Java or C++?

Comment: In C++ or java I would probably simply settle for sending 1 byte for each input state..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/1437195 No idea if this works but that could the most optimized solution. I've never played with byteArray. I have no clue if they play well with socket.io.

Comment: This seems like it would definitely work with my setup, I might try this out, but will probably test it against the solution suggested in the comments above now that I have read about the bit masking operators in javascript. Thanks.